# GCM onHandleIntent(Intent intent) not being called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

My onHandleIntent(Intent intent) function in `gcmIntentService` has the registration for `GCM` as well as the call variable to another function that sends the gcm token to the back-end db. While I run my `MainActivity` the constructor of `GcmintentService` gets called while onHandleIntent doesnt. this is my `GcmIntentService`.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};
    String senderId = "1048700326431";

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public GcmIntentService() {

        super(TAG);
        Log.i(TAG, "ALWAYS IN HERE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, " NOW I NEED IT IN HERE");

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // [START get_token]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            // [END get_token]
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
        }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
            final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("id", token);

            client.post("", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    // called before request is started
                }

                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, PreferenceActivity.Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                }

                public void onFailure(int statusCode, PreferenceActivity.Header[] headers, JSONObject errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                    // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                }

                @Override
                public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                    // called when request is retried
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add code showing how you are starting the GcmIntentService from your MainActivity?

Comment: It is possible you have problem with your broadcast receiver, you can try the [sample GCM android code](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android). It has sample code about subscribe and unsubscribe to a topic.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue but solved it by adding this to the manifest:

```
<service
            android:name="com.futec.h2o.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing this on your manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="your.package.name.RegistrationIntentService"
    android:exported="false">
</service>
```